# MacBookPro 5,1 - Windows 10 - Right Click

Tags: macbook, boot-camp, windows-10

Anyone have any ideas on how to get right-click to work on Windows 10 installed via bootcamp on an older Macbook Pro?  Every version of apple's windows bootcamp drivers that I've tried to install tell me they are not for this system.

Thx

Comment: Please leave a comment on why the down vote so that I can improve the question.

Comment: There are no bootcamp drivers for Win10 yet.

Comment: Anyway to install the ones for windows 7 or 8?  They are usually compatible.